# laravel auth middleware not redirectly on intended page

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I am using hesto/multi-auth package

as default if i have assigned the auth middleware to a route the so after login it should redirect me back to the intended page but it's doing only the first time..

everything working exactly i want only the first time but once i logout and try to access the route again it does go to login page and than redirects to the user/home, but first time it works perfect see the 40 sec video
http://neelnetworks.org/video/laravel.mp4
any solution for this?

these are my web routes

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@getIndex')->middleware('user');

Route::group(['prefix' => 'user'], function () {
  Route::get('/login', 'UserAuth\LoginController@showLoginForm');
  Route::post('/login', 'UserAuth\LoginController@login');
  Route::post('/logout', 'UserAuth\LoginController@logout');

  Route::get('/register', 'UserAuth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm');
  Route::post('/register', 'UserAuth\RegisterController@register');

  Route::post('/password/email', 'UserAuth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
  Route::post('/password/reset', 'UserAuth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
  Route::get('/password/reset', 'UserAuth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm');
  Route::get('/password/reset/{token}', 'UserAuth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm');

});
```

here is my Pages Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PagesController extends Controller
{

   public function getIndex()
   {

    return "hello";
   }
}
```

first time it works perfectly why not after we logged in once?

it works again if i clear all my cache and cookies, is this a default behaviour or is this a bug in laravel? can you please clarify or is it a issue with the package

the issue has been raised in github https://github.com/Hesto/multi-auth/issues/46

Comment: Try to debug your session. Most probably laravel stores a specific route in "intended". This will not bes stored on initial login / setup. But after you were logged in once it might be in your session. You should be able to see it if you just dump out everything. Try to find our if there's an value in "intent" and if so - try to find where it gets set.

Comment: I dont find any variable set in sessions only thing i find is in cookies XSRF-TOKEN and laravel_session nothing else, the session remains empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after so much of digging i found out the correct solution

in RedirectIfNot{guard-name} eg RedirectIfNotAdmin

we need to add this line

```
session()->put('url.intended', url()->current());
```

so the middleware will look like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfNotAdmin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = 'admin')
    {

        if (!Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            session()->put('url.intended', url()->current());
            return redirect('/admin/login');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make your showLoginForm method like this inside your UserAuth/LoginController.php

```
public function showLoginForm()
{
    session()->put('url.intended',url()->previous());
    return view('user.auth.login');
}
```

Because it changes the previous url when posting form to /user/login and you will be redirected to /user/home if you logged in

Comment: Thank you dear.. it works perfect but i also have to remove the $redirectTo variable in order this to work.. thanks a lot

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Default redirect for laravel after login is to go to /home set in the LoginController:

```
use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

and there is default middleware RedirectIfAuthenticated

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

and in app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php

```
class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

So that is where you need to make changes in order to work your way...

Comment: i think you dint understand my problem.. go to this link https://github.com/Hesto/multi-auth/issues/46 and try to understand what i am trying to say

Comment: As i understand now, you are not using plain Laravel, this is some external "plugin" ?

Comment: yup it's a laravel package